# Number of ways to arrange 3 boys and 5 girls in line if the boys must stand next to each other?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm having difficulty with the following question:

*In how many ways can three boys and five girls stand in a straight line, if the boys must stand next to each other?*

It says that the answer is $3!$ x $5!$ x $6$ - The six representing the six places for boys.  How did they get that number?

Isn't there another way to do it, by using combinations and treating the 'three boys' as ONE group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your idea of grouping the boys in one group is entirely sound. There are 6 ways to place that group of boys in the line, $5!=120$ ways of arranging the girls after that and $3!=6$ ways of arranging the boys *within* their cluster, so the answer must be $6\times5!\times3!=4320$ (which is exactly the same form as the given answer).

Comment: Alternatively, there are $6!$ ways of arranging the 5 girls plus the group of boys, and for each of those, there are $3!$ ways of permuting the boys internally. (Of course, this gives the same result: $6\cdot 5!=6!$.)

Comment: Shorter, yes, but mine does match the form given (with the 6 taken out).

Comment: yes, of course. I was just pointing this out because I believe it is the way the OP wants to think about the problem.